# How to post data from ViewModel into a controller method?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post data from a JavaScript function into a controller method. It's working fine when I have a simple model, but it's not working when I try to post data when working with a ViewModel that contains multiple objects.
In another way, I have a login page, and I'm posting the data to the login method like this from my view

View:

```html
     <input type="text" name="username" >   
     <input type="password" name="password">
     <button type="submit" id="postIt">Log in</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#postIt").click(function() {
    postIt();
});

function postIt() {
    var usr = $("#username").val();
    var pwd = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/Login",
        data: {
            "Username": usr,
            "Password": pwd
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.result) {
                alert(data.message);
            } else {
                // unauthorized
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here's my controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(LoginModel data)
{  
    //some code
}
```

When I work with a simple model like `LoginModel` that contains username and password, everything works just fine. But in my case I'm working with a ViewModel that contains loads of tables and lists, and when I tried to pass ViewModel in the controller like this

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(ViewModel data)
{  
    //some code
}
```

And my ViewModel contains

```cs
public class myViewModel
{
    public LoginModel LoginModal { get; set; }
    public List<Users> UsersV { get; set; }
    public List<Images> ImagesV { get; set; }
    public List<Videos> VideosV { get; set; }
    public List<Notes> NotesV { get; set; }
    ///...
}
```

I found out that the data is null, but it wasn't when I was using the `LoginModel`, so is there any way to make this code work?

Comment: What if instead of directly submitting the Username and Password fields.. just change that to `data: $("form").serialize()`?  Then you don't have to change anything in your controller.  But the main problem is that your parameters in your `data` attribute have to match your parameters in your controller method.

Comment: Any reason as to why you're not using Razor to build your forms?  Much easier to maintain in my opinion and it makes the properties that you want to submit to the controller strongly typed to the model, but I am a bit bias towards razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**

0) please, fix your naming in ViewModel (LoginModAl => LoginModEl)

1) put this

```
public JsonResult Login([FromBody]ViewModel data)
```

please, check this one [binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-uDy8mun8nDUN3r1TRpD42A&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-uDy8mun8nDUN3r1TRpD42A&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__ynesk6c9d0kfrw1hxkpoxiopbn2xheusp36g6rum00)(7593)(1243925)(je6NUbpObpQ-uDy8mun8nDUN3r1TRpD42A)()&irclickid=_ynesk6c9d0kfrw1hxkpoxiopbn2xheusp36g6rum00&view=aspnetcore-2.2)

2) you need to add id, because you got undefined fields, like this:
[image]

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" >   
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
```

3) then, you need add contentType and Json.stringify:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/Login",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "loginModel":{
                "Username": usr,
                "Password": pwd
            }

        }),
```

I create new app and its looks fine:
client data:
[image]

and dto in controller:
[image]

i hope in this time it`ll be helpful

Answer (score 0):

When posting data into MVC, you'll need to match your properties with the parameters being posted.

In your javascript your are posting an object that looks like this:

```
{    
    "Username": usr,
    "Password": pwd
}
```

But your view model is expecting something like:

```
{
    "LoginModal": {
        "Username": usr,
        "Password": pwd
    }
}
```

One way to fix this is to modify the javascript:

```
function postIt() {
    var usr = $("#username").val();
    var pwd = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/Login",
        data: {
            "LoginModal": {
                "Username": usr,
                "Password": pwd
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.result) {
                alert(data.message);
            } else {
                // unauthorized
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**However, I would not recommend this.** You are trying to do too much with the view model and should consider breaking these into separate `ViewModels` and `Views`

Comment: Could the OP just do `data: $("form").serialize()`?

Comment: Yes. And that would be my recommendation, I just didn’t know enough about OPs HTML to feel comfortable recommending it. OP would have to change the html input names in that scenario too. To LoginModal.username

Comment: True.  Strange as to why the OP is using MVC but not using Razor to build his/her forms.. to tie the properties to the model.. strongly-typed would be perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however I did what you said exactly, but after putting a break point on my controller method, I can see that the view model is passing all the elements in it, but they are all empty, including the login Model.

Comment: @riario it's probably due to the potential typo in your original question: `public LoginModel LoginModal { get; set; }` If you are using `LoginModal` as the property name, my solution should work. If you are using `LoginModel`, the javascript would need to be adjusted accordingly.