# Creating a ViewModel in MVC from Javascript for a Post method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a Partial View that is a submission form for creating a a new ProductionGoal model.  It uses ProductionLineViewModel to create that.

My main question is how to pass that data into my CreateNewProductionGoal controller method.  I wrote some cursory JS but I am still new to JS and am not totally sure what I am doing.  I used this link as a basis to write my JS:
[How to post data from ViewModel into a controller method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652554/how-to-post-data-from-viewmodel-into-a-controller-method)

Currently when I press the button the **CreateNewProductionGoal method does not get called**.  I am wondering if I need to add something to get that to happen or if I have other errors.

```
<input id="submit" type="button" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="onClick();">

function onClick() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");

    var Employees = $("#productiongoal-text").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
    var ProdLineId = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var ProductionGoalViewModel = { "NumberOfEmployees": Employees, "ProductionLineId": ProdLineId };
    var requestData = {}
    var data = { request: requestData, pgvm: ProductionGoalViewModel }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "ProductionLine/CreateNewProductionGoal",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,  //Creating a ProductionGoalViewModel to pass into the CreateNewProductionGoal method
        success: function (data) {
            location = location;  //Refreshes the page on button press
        }
    });

}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewProductionGoal([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ProductionGoalViewModel pgvm)
    {
        if (pgvm != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProductionGoal pg = new ProductionGoal();
            pg.NumberOfEmployees = pgvm.NumberOfEmployees;
            pg.NumberOfUnits = _prodLineService.Find(pgvm.ProductionLineId).UPE * pgvm.NumberOfEmployees;
            pg.ProductionLineId = pgvm.ProductionLineId;
            pg.ProdLine = _prodLineService.Find(pgvm.ProductionLineId);
            pgvm.NumberOfUnits = pg.NumberOfUnits;
            pgvm.Id = pg.Id;
            pgvm.CreatedAt = pg.CreatedAt;
            _prodGoalService.Insert(pg);
        }
        return Json(new[] { pgvm }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

I want the button press to pass a view model that has NumberOfEmployees and ProductionLineId to the CreateNewProductionGoal method.

I can try to clarify more if needed.

EDIT:

```
var ProductionGoalViewModel = { "NumberOfEmployees": Employees, "ProductionLineId": ProdLineId };
var data = { pgvm: ProductionGoalViewModel }

data: data,
```

EDIT 2:

I am now certain that it has something to do with my button not calling the onClick() method.  I put an alert in that method, probably should have done this awhile ago, and that alert is never being shown. Any suggestions?

```
<input id="submit" type="button" class="button" value="Submit">

function onClick() {
    var Employees = $("#productiongoal-text").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
    var ProdLineId = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var ProductionGoalViewModel = { "NumberOfEmployees": Employees, "ProductionLineId": ProdLineId };
    var data = { pgvm: ProductionGoalViewModel }

    alert("I am an alert box!");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "ProductionLine/CreateNewProductionGoal",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,  //Creating a ProductionGoalViewModel to pass into the CreateNewProductionGoal method
        success: function (data) {
            location = location;  //Refreshes the page on button press
        }
    });

}
```

EDIT 3:
I figured out why my button was never able to call the JS functions.  My button was defined in a partial view and the view that the partial was being called in did not contain the script that was being called.  Pretty frustrating but I am glad I am actually able to call something with my button now.  However, I am still not able to call the CreateNewProductionGoal method.  I have updated the original code to match what I currently have.

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify` from the data object in the ajax call - send an actual object instead.

Comment: I tried that and the current issue is that when I press the button the CreateNewProductionGoal method is not called.  However, this code should now just pass the ProductionGoalViewModel into the method correct? Code in edit above

Comment: Your controller is taking two named inputs, yet you're passing none of those named inputs on submit.  As a test, I would try changing your data to: `data: { pgvm: { NumberOfEmployees: Employees, ProductionLineId: ProdLineId }}`

Comment: I am not sure that is the issue anymore.  I have been trying to pass a ProductionGoalViewModel in a multitude of different ways and none of them have been able to get the CreateNewProductionGoal method to get called.  See edit and other answers, I have tried them all.  Maybe there is something wrong with how my Button was created or the JS OnClick() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code all seems correct to me. When using your JS make sure the tags "#___" match correctly. A lot of times this can be a headache to realize.

Also as Hafiz mentioned above you need to pass two parameters.

```
var requestdata ={ };
var pgvmdata = { "NumberOfEmployees": Employees,
                "ProductionLineId": ProdLineId };

var data = {request:requestdata ,pgvm:pgvmdata}
$.ajax({
        url: "/ProductionLine/CreateNewProductionGoal",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            location = location;  //Refreshes the page on button press
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow, I checked the tags and one was off by a character.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this issue just because you have to pass two parameters and you try to pass only one. I don't know what exactly you have to pass for request so it's up to you so for time being it's empty.

Ajax request looks like.

```
var requestdata ={ };

var pgvmdata = { "NumberOfEmployees": Employees,
                    "ProductionLineId": ProdLineId };

    var data = {request:requestdata ,pgvm:pgvmdata}
    $.ajax({
            url: "/ProductionLine/CreateNewProductionGoal",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                location = location;  //Refreshes the page on button press
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing,

```
       data: JSON.stringify({ 
       //Creating a ProductionGoalViewModel to pass into the CreateNewProductionGoal method
            "ProductionGoalViewModel": {
                "NumberOfEmployees": Employees,
                "ProductionLineId": ProdLineId
            }
        }),
```

To this

```
       data: {
           "NumberOfEmployees": Employees,
           "ProductionLineId": ProdLineId
       },
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not call the CreateNewProductionGoal method.  I am wondering if my button code needs reworked to actually call that method.  Also does this still work so that my CreateNewProductionGoal method will see this input as a ProductionGoalViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you an example.

```
var Employees = $("#productiongoal-text").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
var ProdLineId = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();

var ProductionGoalViewModel = {
    NumberOfEmployees: Employees,
    ProductionLineId: ProdLineId
};

$.ajax({
    url: "ProductionLine/CreateNewProductionGoal",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        //If your controller is parameterized to accept an object then
        parameter_variable_name: ProductionGoalViewModel
    },
    success: function (data) {
        location = location;  //Refreshes the page on button press
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried changing my data to pass the ViewModel in and I am still having trouble getting the Create method to be called.

Comment: Is your create function accepts a parameter of a viewmodel type?

Comment: My CreateNewProductionGoal takes in a ProductionGoalViewModel called pgvm.

Comment: Well then in `data` block of `ajax` call, change `parameter_variable_name` to `pgvm` and make a call